# @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin error: 'Route' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars)

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint

After eslint adds typescript check, there will be an error when the attribute variable in the class definition is Array.
[image]

[image]

[image]

---

this is my eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': ['plugin:vue/essential', '@vue/standard'],
  rules: {},
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    project: "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint']
};
```

Comment: this is my eslintrc.js

Comment: module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true
    },
    'extends': [
        'plugin:vue/essential',
        '@vue/standard'
    ],
    rules: {
    },
    parserOptions: {
        parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
        project: "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint']
};

Comment: You should really put your code in your post rather than use images.  It makes it easier for people to debug.

Comment: ok i will show my code

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### Updated Answer

Disable `no-unused-vars` and enable it with `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error"`

```
"rules": {
  "no-unused-vars": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error"
}
```

Thanks to James Middleton for the correct answer.

#### Outdated

<s>Looking at the eslint repository on github, there have been lots of issues opened  about the `no-unused-vars` rule. Here is some examples:</s>

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/45

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/111

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/171

It's an ongoing problem. Hopefully we can expect this to be resolved soon.

Comment: This worked for me as well. However, I still had to make sure to not only update `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`, but also `@typescript-eslint/parser` (version 4.12.0 for both in my case) to make it work without any false positives.

Answer (score 65):

The solution is to disable the native `no-unused-vars` so that only the TS one is enabled. The former is likely to be enabled if you extend a config in ESLint. Add the rules below to your ESLint config.

```js
"rules": {
  "no-unused-vars": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error"
}
```

Comment: How can one make sure only to omit the errors on imports?

Comment: Its an old answer but this is not a solution, since via this nothing is checked for unused variables, intention is to pass the rule for the types being used in some Generics and fails the rule when someone declared the variable and not used. I want to apply the rule of _ to ignore the variable, this does not supports, if I configures it with the rules of https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars then it starts complaining for unused TYPES.

Answer (score 1):

If someone are still having the issue, I add `"extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],` on the .eslintrc.json file and the problem get solved.