# ESLint dilemma "Defined but never used" VS "Cannot find name" when using import for typehinting

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, typescript-eslint

I just came accross a linting dilemma and I need your help to know what should be done. I'm using

```
$ yarn lint -v
yarn run v1.22.4
$ eslint . -v
v6.8.0
```

With plugins `vue` and `@typescript-eslint` and I have this in a .ts file :

```
import Vue, { VNode } from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend ({
  render(createElement): VNode {
    return createElement('div',
      {},
      'Simple reproducible example'
    );
  }
});
```

I get the error :

```
 error  in ./src/components/Demo.ts

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

/full/path/to/src/components/Demo.ts
  1:15  error  'VNode' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

And the web app served by `yarn serve` (`vue-cli`) shows the same error rendering it unignorable. Using the import to typehint doesn't seem to count as "using" it. So I just removed the import but then I have this error :

```
ERROR in /full/path/to/src/components/Demo.ts(302,26):
4:26 Cannot find name 'VNode'.
    2 | 
    3 | export default Vue.extend ({
  > 4 |   render(createElement): VNode {
      |                          ^
    5 |     return createElement('div',
    6 |       {},
    7 |       'Simple reproducible example'
```

Which somehow seems better because at least I can navigate the web app served by yarn serve. Any idea of to deal with this error the right way ?

### EDIT : `.eslintrc.js` file content

```
module.exports = {
  'env': {
    'browser': true,
    'es6': true,
    'node': true
  },
  'extends': [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended'
  ],
  'globals': {
    'Atomics': 'readonly',
    'SharedArrayBuffer': 'readonly'
  },
  'parserOptions': {
    'ecmaVersion': 2018,
    'parser': '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    'sourceType': 'module'
  },
  'plugins': [
    'vue',
    '@typescript-eslint'
  ],
  'rules': {
    'indent': [
      'error',
      2
    ],
    'linebreak-style': [
      'error',
      'unix'
    ],
    'quotes': [
      'error',
      'single'
    ],
    'semi': [
      'error',
      'always'
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55439681/7456788)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to configure the parser for `eslint` to use `@typescript-eslint/parser` instead of `espree`. Typescript is parsed differently than plain Javascript and not all lint rules applicable to code written in Javascript apply to that in Typescript.

[Configuration section of @typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md#configuration) project provides a sample `.eslintrc.js` file you can begin with.

You can extend this configuration with plugins for `vue`.

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:vue/recommended',
    '@vue/standard',
    '@vue/typescript'
  ],
};
```

Comment: Like I said, I have `typescript-eslint` and `vue` plugins already installed. I will update my question to add the eslintrc file

Comment: Do you use the vue-cli in your project?

Comment: Yes.
I really appreciate your help, could you please try the reproducible example ?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/osule/explore-typed-vue/commit/33425f6c751957de352bb45506d724d4fd1c0dec#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2R40-R45) you'll find the configuration for eslint in the demo project I set up. So far the differences with yours are the missing `@vue/standard` and `@vue/typescript`. It is also important to compare how the `tslint.json` file in the demo project may be different from yours.