# Typescript type an object with function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have few functions defined like below and I tried defining the type as `: {[key: string]: any }` and `: {[key: string]: Function }` but due to the eslint rules, [no-explicit-any](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any/) and [ban-types](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/) I couldn't use those type definitions.

The reason for the below structure is that I have a dynamic code that calls the below function based on the value ( ex: someDefinition(someVar), where someVar is based on a value passed)

```
 const someDefinitions: {[key: string]: any } = {
    A: (v: string): string => 'Returning A',
    B: (v: string): string => 'Returning B with ' + v,
    C: (v: string): string => 'Returning C',
 };
```

Is there any way to define the types satisfying the rules?

Comment: use `(string) => string`

Comment: @DanielA.White  I assume you mean -> `(value:string) => string`

Comment: A bonus when you get the type correct, `{[key: string]: (a:string) => string }`  you'll get implicit types too, so that you can do -> `A: v => 'Returning A',`

Comment: Thanks @Keith, a step forward but I am now getting `'a' is defined but never used.eslint (no-unused-vars)`

Comment: @Keith It works just needed to update the rules based on the https://stackoverflow.com/a/56848207/297641. Thanks again. If you could post yours as answer, I could mark it and close.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an interface:

```
interface Foo {
  A(v: string): string;
  B(v: string): string;
  C(v: string): string;
};
```

Or type:

```
type Foo = {
  A(v: string): string;
  B(v: string): string;
  C(v: string): string;
};
```

And use it as the type of `someDefinitions`:

```
const someDefinitions: Foo = {
  A: (v: string): string => 'Returning A',
  B: (v: string): string => 'Returning B with ' + v,
  C: (v: string): string => 'Returning C',
};
```

You can even short-hand the object now that it's typed:

```
const someDefinitions: Foo = {
  A: (_v) => 'Returning A',
  B: (v) => 'Returning B with ' + v,
  C: (_v) => 'Returning C',
};
```

### Usage:

```js
console.log(someDefinitions.A(''));
console.log(someDefinitions.B('Foo'));
console.log(someDefinitions.C(''));
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I missed to mention the function names in the someDefinition is dynamic and they are based off a keys defined in json.

Comment: @SelvakumarArumugam What does the JSON typically look like? Have you tried [`zod`](https://www.totaltypescript.com/tutorials/zod)?